# download a file from rest api is giving me some garbage value

Tags: java, reactjs, rest

I am trying to download a file from rest API, I am writing code in Java and react. but when i call that rest api it is not downloading that file instead gives me some garbage

```
      @POST
            @Path("/{loginId}")
            @Produces(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
            public Response downloadExportedFile(@PathParam("loginId") String loginId, ExportFileDTO fileDetails) {
        File exportFolder = new File("C://directory");

                        File[] listOfFiles = exportFolder.listFiles();
for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles) {
           if (listOfFile.getName().equals(fileDetails.getFileName())) {
                                            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(listOfFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                            byte[] buffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
                                            return Response.ok(listOfFile)
                                                    .header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + new File(listOfFile.getName()).getName())
                                                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE).build();
                                    }
    }
```

It should download the file instead it is giving me output as 
PK!b�h^�[Content_Types].xml �(����N�0E�H�C�-Jܲ@5��*Q>�ēƪc[�ii����B�j7���{2��h�nm���ƻR����U^7/���%��rZY�@1__�f��q��R4D�AJ�h>����V�ƹ�Z�9����NV�8ʩ����ji){^��-I�"{�v^�P!XS)bR�r��K�s(�3�`c�0��������7M4�����ZƐk+�|\|z�(���P��6h_-[�@�!���Pk���2n�}�?�L��� ��%���d����dN"m,�ǞDO97*�~��ɸ8�O�c|n���E������B��!$}�����;{���[����2���PK!�U0#�L_rels/.rels �(���MO�0��H�����ݐBKwAH�!T~�I����$ݿ'T�G�~����<���!��4��;#�w����qu*&r�Fq���v�����GJy(v��*����K��#F��D��.W  ��=��Z�MY�b���BS�����7��ϛז��
?�9L�ҙ�sbgٮ|�l!��USh9i�b�r:"y_dl��D���|-N��R"4�2�G�%��Z�4�˝y�7  ë��ɂ�����PK!

Comment: `PK!b` indicates this is a ZIP archive

Comment: no it is .xls file

Comment: I double-checked, and find that `PK` is indeed an Excel `.xls` file.  What are you expecting?  If you write that file to disk it will be openable with Excel.  Are you expecting something human-readable?  An Excel file is not directly human-readable.

Comment: I am expecting that after calling this api the file should get download at client machine directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually It is APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM response for a file. we have to handle download functionality at client side AS per Nate's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377541/react-redux-download-file/42245216), the response of Ajax request is not recognized by a browser as a file. It will behave in the same way for all Ajax responses. You need to trigger the download popup manually.

```
downloadFile(fileDetails) {
    let username = getUserName();
    return fetch(`/files/${username}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(fileDetails)
    }).then(response => {
        return response.blob();
    }).then(response => {
        let blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
        let fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        Files.triggerDownload(fileUrl, fileDetails.fileName);
    }).catch((error) => {
        //myerror
    });
}

static triggerDownload(url, fileName) {
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('href', url);
        a.setAttribute('download', fileName);
        a.click();
    }
```

This will download the file at client machine

Comment: I am able to download the file, but I am still getting the gibberish following your code.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642258/restful-produces-binary-file) you should change the `@Produces` annotation to `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)`.

According to [this second stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718102/how-does-jquery-post-deal-with-content-disposition-attachment#answer-9718122) you are asking an impossible question.

Out of curiosity I reproduced your problem here : [see the full gist](https://gist.github.com/smigniot/420ed499e549799c1133eae28c455ea6)

- If you change `@POST` to `@GET` it starts working
- If you keep `@POST`, it has to be posted from a real `form` and can't post `application/json`
- Finally, posting `application/json` means React is doing a programmatic XmlHTTPRequest. The above gist shall convince you there is no user prompt in that case

When you say it 'is giving me output', you're not telling *where* and *how the post was requested* . You *will* have to adapt that part.

Comment: I tried @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) this also.. same output.. then I tried simple .txt .. it is showing me content of that .txt in response but not downloading that file

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the associated mimetype by changing the the parameter of the `@Produces` annotation which basically describes what type of data you transmit in your response.

It should become:

```
@Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
```

Comment: I want generic downloader for that I tried     public final static String APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM = "application/octet-stream"; but my problem is that file is not getting downloaded at client machine