# Returning corrupted file from SFTP server in Java REST API

Tags: java, rest, file, sftp, jsch

I am trying to get a file using a Java REST API from a SFTP Server.

Here I use JSch to connect to SFTP server. The files are PDF, PNG, DOC, etc.

But the returning file is corrupted. Here is my code.

```
String data;
InputStream stream = channelSftp.get("/folder/"+name);
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream,"utf8"));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        data += line+"\n";
    }                          

} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

return Response.ok(data, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + name + "\"") 
    .build();
```

Can you please give me a solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read binary files like PDF/PNG/DOC as a text. That's what corrupts them.

Return the `InputStream` directly, untouched:

```
InputStream stream = channelSftp.get("/folder/"+name);
return Response.ok(stream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + name + "\"") 
    .build();
```

See also [RESTful produces binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7642258/850848).